# Can I spy on an X-session if I am logged in as root?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, x11forwarding

If I were logged into a remote machine as root with ssh -X, how would I go about viewing a particular X11 session that another logged in user was using? (that includes solutions such as remotely installing VNC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add vnc module to X11 config

check http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-279069.html